# Appveyor cannot find test coverage

Tags: xunit, opencover, appveyor, .net-standard

I have a small project (.netstandard 1.0 + net45) on [github](https://github.com/umutozel/Giver) which I integrated with Appveyor.
I'm using xunit for unit tests and opencover for test coverage.
I cannot get Appveyor to commit test results, here is the output:

> Committing...
>   No results, this could be for a number of reasons. The most common reasons are:
>       1) missing PDBs for the assemblies that match the filter please review the
>       output file and refer to the Usage guide (Usage.rtf) about filters.
>       2) the profiler may not be registered correctly, please refer to the Usage
>       guide and the -register switch.

Here is my script:

`- .\tools\OpenCover.4.6.519\tools\OpenCover.Console.exe \
  -target:"c:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" \
  -targetargs:"test -f netcoreapp1.1 -c %CONFIGURATION% Giver.Tests/Giver.Tests.csproj" \
  -mergeoutput \
  -hideskipped:File \
  -output:opencoverCoverage.xml \
  -oldStyle \
  -filter:"+[Giver*]* -[Giver.*Tests*]*" \
  -searchdirs:Giver.Tests/bin/%CONFIGURATION%/netcoreapp1.1 \
  -register:user`

DebugType is full for all projects.

I probably tried most of the combinations for OpenCover.Console arguments.

The same script works on my machine (after replacing %CONFIGURATION%).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it was totally my mistake.

If you change *DebugType* to *Full* using *Project Properties* page (Visual Studio), beware, it will add a condition like this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
```

I am using Release configuration for Appveyor build, so this condition will not be met and portable .pdb will be generated (opencover only works with *Full* .pdb).

After deleting this condition, everything works fine.